# How can I paste an image onto an icon?

Tags: icons

This is a simple operation in Mac. You copy the image you want to use to the clipboard, get the properties of the file, click on the icon, and then paste your image. Done. Anything like this in Ubuntu?

Comment: What kind of icons are we talking about ? Desktop icons or ... ?

Comment: Do you want to change the icon of a folder to an image?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Your question is not clear as it is stated. could you please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and I'm wanting to change the generic icon of a particular folder (which I access in Dolphin file manager) to an image. The image is a jpeg (or does it need to be in some other format?). Is there a size limit to the image? Is the process of doing the change as I described in my original question?

Answer (score 0):

No. In Ubuntu, after clicking on the icon in the properties window of a file, select the graphics file that you want to use as the icon.

Comment: Vanadium: Thanks for you answer. Very helpful to a Linux nwebie

Comment: @nuku I see you use KDE, but is is likely the same there. Please accept the question (click the checkmark next to it) if it helped you - also helps other users to see where a good resolution was obtained.